# How to generate JPA metamodel to another module

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

In my 3 layer maven application (enterprise application archetype with an extra module for domain-related classes) I'd like to keep the domain module as clean as possible. My persistence.xml, for example, is in the ejb module. Following that train of thought, I'd like to generate the JPA static metamodel classes also on the EJB module, even though the entities are not there, but I can't make it work.

Is it possible to do that kind of setup? I'm using eclipselink, btw.

Comment: Use Netbeans select Enterprise Application from Maven. This create the project by separating EJB with JPA module to Web module.

Comment: I'd like to keep the JPA module separated, so it'll need a project for itself.

Comment: This related question may provide some help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946542/running-eclipselink-metamodel-generator-in-sbt